# Best way to build a cross-platform and custom-skinned application with Python

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform, skinning

Features needed:

1. A framework, allowing me to build tab-based application with custom design (like in [Hotot twitter client](http://hotot.org/)), keeping the native os window frame.
2. Compatible with Python.
3. My application will be running under Win/OsX/Linux/.
4. No Flash/Flex/AIR.

I also would like to ask if PySide does meet my requirements and is it worse or better than wxPython and Tkinter mentioned already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of Hotot.

according to your requirements, the key for you to choose a framework is the UI framework should be able to access webview conveniently.

Hotot has several wrappers for different platforms. On Linux, we have both Qt and GTK version, on Windows, we provide a Qt version, on Mac, we have a Cocoa version, and of course we have a Chrome version. In a word, all they can easily access webkit.

PS: [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) is another good choice for native appearance.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html). It works on every platform that Python supports, is relatively easy to program in, looks pretty good on most platforms, and has the features you want. It's also built-in for most versions of Python, so your users (in many cases) will not have to install any external dependencies.

I find that Tkinter looks best on Mac OSX and Windows, and slightly outdated on some Gnome desktops. The most important feature, however, is that the API is extremely clean and easy to use and it is very lightweight. PyQt has a similar feature set, but, in my experience, its performance is significantly degraded when compared to Tkinter.

PySide is Nokia's Qt binding for Python. I'm not aware of what the differences are between it and PyQt. Ultimately, most GUI toolkits for Python are going to be cross platform and support the functionality you need. I suggest Tkinter because I feel it is the easiest and most pleasurable way to program GUI applications in Python.

Comment: It does look pretty, now.   Am I the only guy out there who still remembers how ugly it USED to look, and thus avoids using it? But I suspect, that in the end, its ubiquity and simplicity and reduced size of its redistributables, as compared with wxWidgets, makes it a better choice for many people.

Comment: @Warren it did use to look awful. It still doesn't look perfect under Gnome, but it looks as good as Cocoa on OSX and WPF on Windows, IMO. Dunno about KDE.

Comment: @Alexander sure. Python IDLE (which you probably have): Windows XP http://www.skylit.com/python/Appx-A-Fig4.jpg Windows 7 http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp182/lab/images/IDLE_start.jpg Mac http://blog.flairpy.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/picture-2.png Gnome http://media.photobucket.com/image/python%20idle%20screenshot/Ubermensch69/Screenshot.png

Comment: In theory you can use the ttk (themed tk) widgets, and create your own themes. The reality is, creating a theme is difficult. For one, it's just a difficult thing to do unless you're a color expert. Second, documentation on creating themes for use with ttk is scant. But it _is_ possible as witnessed by the fact that ttk ships with themes for windows and osx, along with a couple for *nix.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to the advices given by other people, I suggest you to use [PyQt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt) which is a Python binding to [Qt framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29). It's widely used, cross-platform and feature-full.

Comment: Thank you, added PySide idea to the question.

Comment: I had never heard of PySide.  Interesting new wrapper.  What happened to PyQT wrappers? Oh I see, they've gone all Money oriented. :-)

Comment: PySide is developed by Qt creators, because, yes, PyQt guys keep it non-free.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) (based on [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)). If you want to make it web-based, look into using [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you mentioned PyHotOt, and it says (on its web site) that it uses pywebkitgtk, and PyGTK.   PyGTK/PyWebKitGTK exists for windows. Did you check it out?  I think OS X would be the weak link on GTK, but maybe it's pretty good too.